# Settings for Wordpress after converting from Apache to Nginx + PHP-FPM

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, php

I have a site that is hosted on a server that uses PHP, Apache. I would like to migrate this site another host that is running on PHP-FPM and Nginx. Obviously, changing the nameservers, mysql dump and transferring the actual wp folder is the easier part. But, I would like to know what settings to modify before migrating the site.

As far as I know, the only thing I have to worry about is pretty urls. I may be able to do 
 `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` if it works. If not however, the I will risk the site being defaces for several hours before reversing the nameserver to it's original state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great article here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx on NGINX configs for Wordpress, here is the one I use for normal (not-multisite) wordpress. I save this in a separate file (wordpress.conf) and then include it in server blocks for wordpress-powered sites:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}

# Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
}

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
location ~* ^/wp-content/uploads/.*.php$ {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
}

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory for multisite
location ~* /files/(.*).php$ {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
}

# WordPress single blog rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if rules below fail.                                                    

# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 24h;
        log_not_found off;
}

# Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching plugin (if used).
#include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;
#include global/wordpress-w3-total-cache.conf;

# Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ \.php$ {
        # Zero-day exploit defense.
        # http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
        # Won't work properly (404 error) if the file is not stored on this server, which is entirely possible with php-fpm/php-fcgi.
        # Comment the 'try_files' line out if you set up php-fpm/php-fcgi on another machine.  And then cross your fingers that you won'
t get hacked.
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}
```